# preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm using one to many relation on my User and Student eloquent. And I am using Laravel's Notifications to send mails to users.

I'm trying to send mail, the content is the people that have been born on that day. Relations work great, I have seperate user_id column in my Student table to which user is created that Student. And when sending mails, it should only send the people that've been created by authentiacated user.

But when I login, I get error: **preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given**

**That is the code that I'm filtering users by date**

`$user->students()->where('birth_date','=', Carbon::today())`

**How I call *toMail* method**

`$user->notify(new BirthdayReminder())` (on authenticated in LoginController)

**My *toMail* method**

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->from('admin@site.com')
                    ->line('Hello, '.User::first()->name.'!')
                    ->line('Today is birthday of:')
                    ->line($user->students()->where('birth_date','=', Carbon::today()));
    }
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Use `Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')` instead of `Carbon::today()` , if `birth_date` format is `Y-m-d`

Comment: Didn't solve the problem

Comment: What's in your `BirthdayReminder` and where is the error coming from (file name, even if it's a vendor file)?

Comment: `BirthdayReminder` is the notification file that I've created with `make:notification`,

Comment: And the error comes from `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SimpleMessage`

Comment: I've updated the question with my toMail function in `BirthdayReminder`

Comment: It should return students that `birth_date` column is today.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably coming from the last line where that says:

`->line($user->students()->where('birth_date','=', Carbon::today()))`

Not sure what you are hoping to achieve with this. But this line will return a query builder which is not a string.

You could try something like this instead:

```php
$user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);

$mail = (new MailMessage)
    ->from('admin@site.com')
    ->line('Hello, '.User::first()->name.'!')
    ->line('Today is birthday of:');

foreach ($user->students()->where('birth_date', Carbon::today())->pluck('name') as $userName) {
    $mail = $mail->line($userName);
}

return $mail;
```

Comment: I related my two eloquents with one to many, and that line should return records that `birth_date` column equals to today

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is (probably) in `line($user->students()->where('birth_date','=', Carbon::today()))`

This will try to put a line with the result of `$user->students()->where('birth_date','=', Carbon::today())` but this result is a collection of students.

If you want to get all the names instead do something like:

```
line($user->students()->where('birth_date','=', Carbon::today())->pluck('name')->implode(','));
```

this will return a comma separated string of all the names of the students.

You can manipulate those results any way you want but the point is the end result that goes in `line(...)` needs to be a string